# How to update chokidar files selection correctly without declaring new variable?

Tags: node.js, chokidar

Assume that we created the chokidar instance, but then files selection that should be watched has been changed. If I don't want to create a new variable, is it enough just to assign new chokidar watcher with new files selection to same variable? Of course, in below code, I would that `filesSelection1` will no be watched anymore.

```
let filesSelection1 = 'test/files/selection/1/**.*';
let filesSelection2 = 'test/files/selection/2/**.*';

let stylesWatcher = chokidar.watch(filesSelection1);

// is it correct?
stylesWatcher = chokidar.watch(filesSelection2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know **chokidar** (and NodeJS streams) implementation in details, but after some experiments I understood that `stylesWatcher = null` in below code will not terminate watching:

```
let stylesWatcher = chokidar.watch(filesSelection1);
stylesWatcher = null;
```

If you want to update **chokidar** watcher without watching will be terminated, below code passed the tests:

```
let stylesWatcher = chokidar.watch(filesSelection1);
let bufferedOldWatcher = stylesWatcher;
stylesWatcher = chokidar.watch(filesSelection2);
bufferedOldWatcher.close(); // now we can close watching on old instance
```